# Has a fighter ever stopped fighting because opponent is unable to defend themselves, even though the referee hasn't stopped the fight?

Tags: boxing, martial-arts

Inspired by [If a professional fighter dies in a ring, is it considered a murder? Would his opponent go to jail?](https://nodum.org/if-a-professional-fighter-dies-in-a-ring-is-it-considered-a-murder-would-his-opponent-get-charged-video/)

> Similar incident happened in   1960 in a boxing match between Benny Paret and Emile Griffith. In the twelfth round Griffith pushed Paret to the corner and started punching him to the head very hard. Paret was defenceless at that point, but referee did not stop the fight as he was still standing. Crowd was shocked seeing Griffith landing very strong uppercuts to Paret's head, but his coach did not throw the towel in either. Ten days later Paret was announced dead. Griffith was called a murderer, but never faced any charges. Later he was forgiven by Paret's son and admitted crying remembering the incident. He got furious after Paret's homophobic remarks – Griffith was bisexual.

Has anyone in Griffith's position ever stopped fighting because their opponent is clearly unable to defend themselves, even though the referee hasn't stopped the fight?

I'm tagging the question with "boxing", even though I'm also interested in all combat sports.